# How to download all pdf with wget from a systematically changing url?

Tags: pdf, download, wget

I would like to download a lot of `pdf` with `wget` from the online library "Enrique Bolaños" (http://enriquebolanos.org).

The link with the first `pdf` I like to download is

http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-1961-01-02.pdf

All other `pdf` are linked by `url` which follow a certain pattern: they have the dates of publication in them, e. g.

for Januar 3, 1961: http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-1961-01-03.pdf

for Januar 4, 1961: http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-1961-01-04.pdf.

1. How can I download all available `pdf` from Januar 2, 1961 to
   Dezember 19, 1997 with `wget` at once?
2. If this is not possible, how can I download all `pdf` for one year
   of publication in `wget`, e. g. first all `pdf` from 1961, then 1962 etc.?

I have this command so far, resulting in downloading only all available `pdf` for Januar 1961:

```
wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-1961-01-0{1..31}.pdf
```

**Edit:** I now have the following command:

```
wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-19{61..97}-0{1..9}-{01..31}.pdf http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-19{61..97}-{10..12}-{01..31}.pdf
```

However, `wget` tells me that

```
Argument list too long
```

Is there any work around?

I tried the following loop to no avail:

```
for ((i=61; i<=$97; i++)) ; do wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-19$i-0{1..9}-{01..31}.pdf http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-19$i-{10..12}-{01..31}.pdf ; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution to my problem, which is

```
for i in {61..97} ; do wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-19$i-0{1..9}-{01..31}.pdf http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/G-19$i-{10..12}-{01..31}.pdf ; done
```